# STS 3.7.0 Eclipse 4.5 Mars to Support HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: html, css, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-mars

I recently downloaded STS 3.7.0 which is using Eclipse 4.5.0 Mars.

I have Java web application. I need to use HTML5, CSS3 and AngularJS. I installed AngularJS plugin. But the new version also doesn't support CSS3. Which is best plugin I can use for eclipse as of now? I saw a post about aptana.com but it is now Appcelerator and I'm not able to install the plugin.

I see [this link on how to install WTP](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F). But I need to know whether it supports CSS3 and HTML5. Because it doesn't says that. If it supports, How can I install?

Do I need to install only *Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development* for that?

Because in STS 3.6.4 I tried to install all the listed features from the URL and STS is not opening. So i thought to use latest version of STS.

Which is the best option?

Comment: STS 3.7 Mars or Luna + WTP Web and XML probably. Ensure you use the latest WTP for Mars update site. WTP does have support for HTML and CSS, but not sure about the versions.

Comment: If it doesn't support CSS3 and HTML5, I don't need to use WTP updates. There is update site for Mars. Is there any good plugin? and how can I enable it?

Comment: I think the WTP components in Eclipse (pre-installed into the STS distribution) support CSS3, but the overall experience for doing JavaScript development is (sadly) not great.

Comment: I don't see any support for CSS3. I don't see auto complete for border-radius. I have some CSS3 styles already in a file. When I press Ctrl_Shift+F to align the format, the lines are coming in different lines and styles are not applying.